# Find absolute html path given relative href using R

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, rvest

I'm new to `html` but playing with a script to download all `PDF` files that a given webpage links to (for fun and avoiding boring manual work) and I can't to find where in the `html` document I should look for the data that completes relative paths - I know it is possible since my web browser can do it.

*Example*: I trying to scrape lecture notes linked to on [this page from ocw.mit.edu](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/MIT6_006F11_lec01.pdf) using `R` package `rvest` looking at the raw `html` or accessing the `href` attribute of `a` "nodes" I only get relative paths:

```
library(rvest)
url <- paste0("https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/",
  "electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/",
  "6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-notes/")

# Read webpage and extract all links
links_all <- read_html(url)  %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href")

# Extract only href ending in "pdf"
links_pdf <- grep("pdf$", tolower(links_all), value = TRUE)
links_pdf[1] 
[1] "/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/mit6_006f11_lec01.pdf"
```

Comment: Doesn't your webbrowser assume sth like `sub("(?i-)(https?://[^/]+).*", "\\1", url)`, when there's nothing else set (e.g. using <base>)?

Comment: Seems like it - that's my current hypothesis. Will go with something like that until better info or it fails....

Comment: Just tested your code out of interest for your question, in this example the missing absolute path your are refering to is in url no ? If you are testing an htlm page using rvest then you have access to the full path ? In which case won't you be able to access to this ?

Comment: The missing part is in the url, and it seems, only in the url. I was expecting it to be somewhere in the `html` file...

Comment: @lukeA may I ask about the `(?i-)` part of the regex expression?

Comment: @snoram This modifier makes the regular expression case insensitive. You could also use the argument `ignore.case=TRUE` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution that I have found as of today is using the `url_absolute(x, base)` function of the `xml2` package. For the base parameter, you use the url of the page you retrieved the source from.

This seems less error prone than trying to extract the base url of the address via regexp.